# Horizontal menu with dropdown's size between menu item's width an max-width

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I need help with a simple horizontal menu with dropdowns.

I want the `.drop` size to be not smaller than the `.item` size and as big as possible in the `max-width` limit.

**The problem is**: the `.drop` doesn't expand to `max-width`.

```css
div {
  background: #333;
  color: white;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
}

.drop {
  background: #666;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 400px;
  min-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

.item:hover .drop {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="item">Lorem
      <ul class="drop">
        <ul>
          <li>Lorem</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
              consectetur adipiscing elit, 
              sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
              labore et dolore magna aliqua</li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor
      <ul class="drop">
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First the `.item` has no specified width and the `min-width:100%;` overrides `min-width:400px;` thereby making the `.drop` 100% of the parent width. And the parent has no width assigned to it.

Since the `.item` is set to display block then assign a width of 100% to it also.

Comment: `min-width:400px;` is just a typo, it must be `max-width:400px;`. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. you need to wrap the dropdown in one more ul and apply the following ccs rules to achieve this. just set the width and max-width you want accordingly.

```css
div {
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0px;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

a {
  display: block;
}

.drop {
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  /* Width of the width */
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background: transparent;
}

ul li ul {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 250px;
  /* max width it will cover */
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  padding: 0;
  background: #666;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul li .drop li {
  display: table-row;
  /* display like a table-row */
}

.item:hover .drop {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="item">Lorem
      <div class="drop">
        <ul>

          <li>Lorem</li>
          <li>Lorem</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
              consectetur adipiscing elit, 
              sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
              labore et dolore magna aliqua</li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor
      <div class="drop">
        <ul>
          <li>Lorem</li>
          <li>Lorem</li>
          <li>Lorem</li>
          <li>Lorem</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read my question: I want the `.drop` size to be not smaller than the `.item` size